# Angular and Angular material upgrade from v5.x to v6.x

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-material-5, rxjs6

I am trying to update my existing angular project from v5.x to v6.x along with angular material.

I have done the following steps -

1. I deleted existing node_module folder
2. Followed all the steps mentioned here - [update to ng 6](https://www.ngdevelop.tech/upgrade-angular-5-to-6/)
3. Installed latest angular material and cdk and hammer.js as mentioned in latest angular material guide.
4. I re-ran - npm install - deleting earlier node_modules folder and clean npm cache.

BUT When I run ng serve - I get the following errors - Please look at the screen shot attached.

Any help or clue will be highly appreciated!!

[image]

Package.json screenshot-

[image: Package.json]

Comment: What's your package.json?

Comment: use https://update.angular.io/ nice explain..

Comment: I have done all the mentioned steps. Problem is new version of rxjs and new version of angular material Iguess

Answer (score 0):

Try `npm install @angular/cdk --save`.

Also, it would help us a lot if you could post your package.json file.

Comment: I have added a screenshot for package.json

Comment: I have tried doing this - npm install @angular/cdk --save